# Appengine Endpoints Maven Build Error with /generated-sources

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, maven-war-plugin

I am trying to make appengine endpoints work with Maven, but I get the following error every time, i followed the appengine endpoints doc, I couldn't able to find what went wrong,

Error is:

**Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-war) on project Test: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war failed: basedir /Users/Ramesh/git/endpoints/demo/Test/target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints does not exist**

How can I make it work with Maven?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend downloading the source for the "hello world" of Google Cloud Endpoints from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-java-maven), and taking a peek at their POM file.  The issue for me was that I did not have the "appengine-maven-plugin" defined in the correct POM - it needs to be in the WAR's POM so that it can sniff the metadata and generate the right output.